# Calling codeigniter encryption key

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, encryption

I have set the encryption key in **config.php** file

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'az2x@_.@!`~$aezxqy+=@%^&';
```

I want to use this key in password when registering users into the website, right now i am using this method

```
'password' => hash('sha256', $password . 'az2x@_.@!`~$aezxqy+=@%^&')
```

Is there any way i can set the above code like

```
'password' => hash('sha256', $password . $config['encryption_key']),
```

when i do it gives error of undefined $config variable.

Comment: You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security, cryptographic hashes are very fast. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. **Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.**

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest using the built-in php API for password salt/hash and not the method you are using, the encryption key is meant to be used for the encryption class...

```
$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

You use this salted and hashed password stored in the database.

Then verify it when getting it from the DB using:

```
password_verify($password, $result->password)
```

This returns a BOOLEAN so you use it in an if statement:

```
if ( password_verify($password, $result->password) ) {

// do login stuff

} else {

// handle login failure

}
```

Else, you can use the encryption key by the following (strongly suggest against it):

```
$this->config->item('encryption_key');
```

If this doesn't work you are probably writing a helper or something, so you'll need to call the CI instance to get access to the config array.